# Objective-C : Insert string into another string at a certain range

Tags: string, range

i need to insert a string into another string at a certain range.
I know there is the `appendingString` method but i need to insert it at a given range into the string. thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSMutableString insertString:atIndex:` is what you're looking for.

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/insertString:atIndex:).